# Reindex dataframe based on column values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Data**

```
ID  Q1  Q2  Q3
AA  1   2   4
BB  5   5   5
CC  6   7   7
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Q1  Q2  Q3
BB  5   5   5
CC  6   7   7
AA  1   2   4
```

**Doing**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index = ["BB","CC","AA"])
```

This is simply adding the row name, I wish to rea arrange row order based on name. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What's the arrange logic?

Comment: No Particular arrange logic, just looking to see if it is possible to reindex based on column values and not the row number @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: Suppose `df` is DataFrame.
reindex by `df.reindex(["BB","CC","AA"])` is that right?

Comment: I’ll try this  , not sure if I can actually rearrange using values unless using loc. l try thanks @Nguyen